# Why use session bean at all if ultimately its the HttpSession that holds the state

Tags: java, ejb, session-bean

I am new to EJB so please don't mind anything silly in the question.

I have a doubt that someone might be able to solve hopefully.

I have the following Stateful Bean:

```
@Stateful
public class SessionBean implements SessionBeanRemote {

    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
    count++;
    return count;

    }

}
```

And this is the client that invokes the Bean (Servlet)

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        InitialContext ctx;
        HttpSession session = null;
        SessionBeanRemote obj;
        try {
            if (session.getAttribute("myBean") == null) {
                ctx = new InitialContext();
                obj = (SessionBeanRemote) ctx.lookup("SessionBean/remote");
                session.setAttribute("myBean", obj);
            } else {
                obj = (SessionBeanRemote) session.getAttribute("myBean");
            }

            System.out.println(obj.getCount());

        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Now I was wondering if it is ultimately HttpSession that has to hold the session bean then why use EJB at all, why not just store whatever we want to in the session directly rather than having it in the session bean first and then storing that bean in the session.

And also I was wondering if lets say I change my @Stateful annotation to @Stateless and then execute the same code on the client side and store the bean in the session then also I can extract the same bean from the session then what is the difference between stateless and stateful, I know that when new lookup is done there is a chance that same stateless bean might be returned to me where as with stateful bean it is always new when we do a lookup. But is that it?

P.S. As I mentioned earlier, I am new to EJB and all the doubts are based on what I have understood from a few tutorials online and some questions on SO. I have also tried running it locally but unfortunately I am not able to deploy the application on the GlassFish because of  following error   "Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error". I am trying to look into it.

Comment: In addition to the good answer below, never underestimate the value of "this is handled for me automatically".

Comment: @chrylis But it is not being handled automatically, after the lookup I have to store it in the HttpSession so that I get the same instance always. Then why not store a plain object instead of a bean. or why not store a stateless bean as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to give you a simplified answer.

Yes, you have to store reference to the SFSB somewhere, in case of web application in http session, but as Elliott wrote you may have different client types also.

Some benefits of Session bean vs POJO:

- container transaction management
- container security enforcement
- possible remote access via remote interface
- allows to be deployed as separate module (EJB) for potentially better reusability.

If your session bean relies on state, then it is more logical to hold the state in the bean rather than pass all state info in each method call.

Your example is extremely simple, you don't use transactions, persistence, security, so there is no point of using SFSB or even EJB at all.

SFSB are considered to be rather heavyweight, in general should rather be avoided and I'd say majority of web applications don't use them (depends on application requirements really). So you should design your services to be stateless and rather use stateless beans than stateful, then you will have better performance and easier reusability.

So if you plan to use some of the features I provided, you may benefit from EJBs, otherwise you maybe happy with just Http session and business logic in POJOs.

Comment: This is something a newbie would understand.. :-) Thank you my friend. I guess I'll need to look at Transaction, Security to understand the uses of SFSB better. @ Would you hapeen to know any place where I can get the examples or tutorials for those.

Answer (score 1):

They're two unrelated concepts.

If you seperate concerns, and you should. Then the HTTP session and EJB session(s) operate at logically distinct layers. The http session is for holding an individual web browser and user's state. An EJB session is used for holding transactional, scalable and fault-tolerant and "transparently" (and possibly remote) reference(s) within the context of an Enterprise application client.

The fact that you're using EJB(s) to serve web content, does not mean you cannot also use those same EJB(s) to serve JFC/Swing (or JavaFX) clients.

Comment: I am sorry but could you simplify this a bit. As I said new to the concept.

Comment: This answer is simplified. The enterprise version of Java is very complicated. It gives you a lot of tools. For example, you can build applications that **don't** have a web based UI. With a web based UI you can build applications that **don't** use EJB(s). So, what kind of application are you ultimately building and what other integrations must you build and maintain with other systems? Do you need reusable modules? Do you have high availability and SLA requirements? Scaling requirements?

Answer (score 0):

**EJB Sessions**

A session in EJB is maintained using the SessionBeans over the server's JVM. You design beans that can contain business logic or calculations or dynamic pages, and that can be used by the clients. You have two different session beans: Stateful and Stateless.

**Stateful:** is somehow connected with a single client (each bean's object). It maintains the state for that client, can be used only by that client and when the client "dies" then the session bean is "lost". Stateful bean's life-cycle is bind with the client. (very useful in role-based applications/systems)

**Stateless:** A Stateless Session Bean doesn't maintain any state and there is no guarantee that the same client will use the same stateless bean, even for two calls one after the other. The lifecycle of a Stateless Session EJB is slightly different from the one of a Stateful Session EJB. Is EJB Container's responsability to take care of knowing exactly how to track each session and redirect the request from a client to the correct instance of a Session Bean and to same job for every one.

Where:

**HTTPSession:** It is acquired through the request object. You cannot really instantiate a new HttpSession object, and it doesn't contains any business logic or calculation, but is more of a place where to store objects (for client as output or server as input), and for communication of two or more system over the network.

Comment: @Sarx Correct me if I'm wrong but, in all case, you need to store the reference to the Stateful SB in a client session (HTTP for example) as each lookup to the Stateful SB returns a new instance.
So I am jsut wondering why not store a plain object rather than storing a bean.. Whats so special about the bean here.

Comment: HttpSession is only for identifies user let say user profiling. Statefull session bean (create new object for each client) track your identify and dynamically fill data accordingly (role-base) from database say using PersistenceContext. HttpSession is web technology server can maintain a session in many ways such as using cookies or rewriting URLs, and EJB session is java technology server maintain state as objects of java application. I think your as mixing their names.